# Program runs in Eclipse, but exported runnable jar file will not open?

Tags: java, eclipse, file, jar, runnable

It looks like this is a common problem, but none of the previous posts seem to address my issue.

I believe I've narrowed it down to one problem. Any application that uses an InputStream will not open, but all my other applications run fine.

The application runs fine in Eclipse, but the window won't even open when I try to run the jar file.

Task manager shows it pop up for about a second or two, and then disappears.

I have tried all three options for the Library handling upon exporting and none of them fix the issue.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Have you tried running it from the command shell, so that you can see any errors? Or is there a log file you can share?

Comment: I'm unable to run any jar files from command line (even the ones that open perfectly just by clicking on them). I get an error telling me that I'm on 1.7 but 1.6 is required.

Comment: @Dan what does the error say? Add the command you tried and the output it generates to your question, as it's additional information.

Comment: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\CurrentVersion' has value '1.7', but '1.6' is required.

Comment: This is just another general issue completely independent of the original post. It just came up now because I never run jar files from the command prompt.

Comment: I can't understand why running the jar in command prompt would do anything differently from when I just click on it.

Answer (score 9):

Run it from the command line. This will allow you to see the exception that's thrown that's preventing your program from progressing.

```
java -jar YourJar.jar
```

Comment: This is a debugging suggestion best suited as a comment

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late, but I want to prevent people having to search hours for the same Error I just did. In Eclipse the path-String isn't case-sensitive. In the exported Runnable Jar File it is. So make sure all the pathsnames have the capital letters in the right positions, or to be save don't have capital letters at all.

Answer (score 0):

**Setup Your Manifest**

If I had to guess, your manifest doesn't contain your main class OR the classpath is not defined.

*Main-Class*: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html
*Class-Path*: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

If you're using a build tool like maven, it needs to be configured to add these properties: https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html

**Execute Your Jar**

There are two ways to run an executable jar. As an executable jar you need to define the Main-Class and Class-Path in your manifest:

```
java -jar YourJar.jar
```

You can also skip setting up your manifest and define your classpath and main class through the JVM's parameters.

```
java -cp=${PATH_TO_JAR} main.package.MainClass
```